# Hierarchical SQL select-query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using MS SqlServer 2008. And I have a table 'Users'. This table has the key field ID of bigint. And also a field Parents of varchar which encodes all chain of user's parent IDs.
For example:

User table:

```
ID | Parents
1  | null
2  | ..
3  | ..
4  | 3,2,1
```

Here user 1 has no parents and user 4 has a chain of parents 3->2->1. I created a function which parses the user's Parents field and returns result table with user IDs of bigint.

Now I need a query which will select and join IDs of some requested users and theirs parents (order of users and theirs parents is not important). I'm not an SQL expert so all I could come up with is the following:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT
    ID,
    Parents
FROM
[Users]
WHERE
(
     [Users].Name = 'John'
)

UNION ALL

SELECT
    [Users].Id,
    [Users].Parents
FROM [Users], CTE
WHERE
(
    [Users].ID in (SELECT * FROM GetUserParents(CTE.ID, CTE.Parents) )
)) 
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

And basically it works. But performance of this query is very poor. I believe WHERE .. IN .. expression here is a bottle neck. As I understand - instead of just joining the first subquery of CTE (ID's of found users) with results of GetUserParents (ID's of user parents) it has to enumerate all users in the Users table and check whether the each of them is a part of the function's result (and judging on execution plan - Sql Server does distinct order of the result to improve performance of WHERE .. IN .. statement - which is logical by itself but in general is not required for my goal. But this distinct order takes 70% of execution time of the query). So I wonder how this query could be improved or perhaps somebody could suggest some another approach to solve this problem at all?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does `GetUserParents()` do?

Comment: It receives as parameters ID of a user and its varchar representation of parent IDs. And returns table of parsed parent IDs:

Comment: Oh I see. Personally I wouldn't have used a varchar column and created another table with a row for every parent. That way you don't need the function to parse the string.

Comment: Not sure I get your data structure but it looks like [something like this should work for you (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4ccce/1). Might be faster, might not.

Comment: Mikael, Thanks very interesting point of view! I've bit simplified the example. In reality parent ids are stored as varbinary byte arrays of serialized .NET Int64 values. But the GetUserParents() functions knows how to deserialize it to a table of bigint IDs. I tried to convert those IDs to CSV varchars (the same as in the example) to try your approach but unfortunately it works too slow (on 1 million records). In general all what I need - it's a some kind of a select query which can merge all those parent IDs in one set. Sounds like something simple but I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive query in the question looks redundant since you already form the list of IDs needed in `GetUserParents`. Maybe change this into `SELECT` from `Users` and `GetUserParents()` with `WHERE`/`JOIN`.

```
select Users.*
from Users join
     (select ParentId
      from (SELECT * FROM Users where Users.Name='John') as U
           cross apply [GetDocumentParents](U.ID, U.Family, U.Parents))
     as gup
on Users.ID = gup.ParentId
```

Since `GetDocumentParents` expects scalars and `select... where` produces a table, we need to apply the function to each row of the table (even if we "know" there's only one). That's what `apply` does.

I used indents to emphasize the conceptual parts of the query. `(select...) as gup` is the entity `Users` is `join`'d with; `(select...) as U cross apply fn()` is the argument to `FROM`.

The key knowledge to understanding this query is to know how the `cross apply` works:

- it's a part of a `FROM` clause (quite unexpectedly; so the syntax is at [FROM (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))
- it transforms the *table expression left of it*, and the result becomes the argument for the `FROM` (i emphasized this with indent)

The transformation is: for each row, it

- runs a *table expression right of it* (in this case, a call of a table-valued function), using this row
- adds to the result set the *columns from the row*, *followed by* the columns from the call. (In our case, the table returned from the function has a single column named `ParentId`)

  - So, if the call returns multiple rows, the added records will be the same row from the table appended with each row from the function.

This is a `cross apply` so rows will only be added if the function returns anything. If this was the other flavor, `outer apply`, a single row would be added anyway, followed by a `NULL` in the function's column if it returned nothing.

Comment: Exactly. Recursion is not needed here. I just don't know how to merge those parents IDs. If I wrote code in C#.NET I would use something like Users.Where(user => user.Name = "John").SelectMany(user => GetUserParents(user.Id)). But as I said my knowledge in SQL is not enough to find elegant and efficient alternative for my recursive variant. I see another straightforward approach with opening cursor for each found child and then retrieving its parents and inserting them into a temporary table.. but this is an ugly solution and cursors, temporary tables... it's too much for this task.

Comment: Thank you for the sample, looks fine and I tried it before. But it fails with the following error: "The multi-part identifier "CTE.id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
The multi-part identifier "CTE.Parents" could not be bound." Probably CTE tables has some limitations and cannot be used this way?

Comment: Or rather the query does not know where to take those CTE.ID's from. That's way I used in my query this: FROM [Users], CTE
WHERE
(
    [Users].ID in (SELECT * FROM GetUserParents(CTE.ID, CTE.Parents) )
))

Comment: Can you post the source of `GetUserParents` so I can debug this?

Comment: Ok. First of all please note that in reality that Parents field is not a varchar field but varbinary, and there is yet another field Family which is used for some special rules while parsing the Parents filed. I just simplified example in my question, but in general it does not change anything. Please find the whole script which creates a User table with some real data, creates the function, and with my query by this link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24643963/Script.sql.txt .

Comment: The relation between users in that table is following: George - is root, and has two children: Ringo and Paul. John - is child of Paul. So if we search for "John" we should get the result: John, Paul, George.

Comment: Oh, God... Okay, I'm on it :^)

Comment: Well actually as I said it does not change anything, it means that only function's signature has changed a bit :) I just didn't want to break something accidentally in the function itself so I left it as it is.. In reality there is even more behind this sample but I'm trying to keep things simple at least for this question.

Comment: Done. The problem was that `GetDocumentParents` expects scalars so it needs to be applied to each row of the initial select. I'll be adding an explanation now.

Comment: Unbelievable - IT WORKS! I don't understand how does it work and I have to investigate it in details but still. I've been struggling with this problem for the last 2 days and finally you did it! Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: I did my best to explain its structure and workings in the accompanying text. This should be clear enough, just take your time to explore it slowly, thesis by thesis.

Comment: The explanation is very clear. I even do not have to google it :) Thanks!

Comment: The fact is, I _didn't_ find a decent explanation in google and had to learn this the hard way :^)

Answer (score 0):

This "parsing" thing violates even the [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Make `Parents` field contain only the immediate parent (preferably, a foreign key), then an entire subtree can be retrieved with a recursive query.

Comment: Yes I would do it for sure. But unfortunately I'm working with a very complicated legacy application and cannot change the structure of the data and anything else at all. All I can do here - just add a some SELECT expression to retrieve the required data from the database.

Comment: You could monkey-patch around this by introducing duplicating entities and update triggers to keep them synchronized - at the cost of update performance. Not the most elegant solution, of course.